# Text searching with DOMXPath PHP

Tags: php, dom, curl, xpath

**html**

```
<td class="one">
  <div>
    <b>
      <span>item</span>
    </b>
    <div>
      <c>text</c>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

How do you select and echo **item** by searching for **text** ?

I'm having difficulty with the xpath line in PHP.

```
$c = $xpath->query("*/c");
```

**php**

```
<?php
$keyword = "String";
$search = strtolower($keyword);

$target_url = "http://www.example.com/";

//USER AGENT
//$userAgent = 'spider';
$userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';

$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT   => $userAgent,
                CURLOPT_URL             => $target_url,
                CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
                CURLOPT_FAILONERROR     => true,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 20
                );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$html= curl_exec($ch);

if (!$html)
{
    echo "ERROR NUMBER: ".curl_errno($ch);
    echo "ERROR: ".curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$c = $xpath->query("*/c");


foreach($c as $a) { 
    $text = $a->nodeValue;
    echo($text . '<br />');
}


//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($c);
//echo '</pre>';    
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [HTML defines no `c` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html), you won't be able to use [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) unless you also supply the [`LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php), like so:

```
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
```

This sets an appropriate libxml flag to allow you traverse your document without the element checking.